# Gurenberg Block: How to migrate from el-Functions to JSX elements?

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I have read many tutorial and no one is using the el() syntax but the "markup syntax" (JSX?). Here is my example:

This worked fine, but I think I have to migrate to make it easier readable:

```
  edit: function(props) {
    return [
      el(
        BlockControls, { key: 'controls' },
        el( Toolbar, null,
          el(
            IconButton, {
              className: 'components-icon-button components-toolbar__control',
              label: __('Update table of contents', 'simpletoc'),
              onClick: function() {
                sendfakeAttribute(props)
              },
              icon: 'update'
            }
          )
        )
      ),
      el(
        'p', { className: props.className },
        el(
          ServerSideRender, {
            block: props.name,
            attributes: props.attributes
          }
        )
      )
    ];
```

I tried this and it works!

```
  edit: function(props) {
    return (
      <p className={props.className}>
        <ServerSideRender block={props.name} attributes={props.attributes} />
      </p>
    )
  },
```

But then I tried to add the toolbar component and I get a syntax error about my brackets:

```
<BlockControls>
    <Toolbar>
    <IconButton 
      className={components-icon-button components-toolbar__control} 
      label={__('Update table of contents', 'simpletoc')}
      onClick={function() {
        sendfakeAttribute(props)
      }}
      icon={update} 
    />
    </Toolbar>
  </BlockControls>
  <p className={props.className}>
    <ServerSideRender block={props.name} attributes={props.attributes} />
  </p>
```

I think I don't understand how to escape the code correctly. Even if I leave out all the attributes of the icon-button I get this error:

*Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag*

Any guidance on that? More examples would be great in the documentation.

Comment: You can't return multiple things in a function unless you put them in an array, JSX is no different

Answer (score 4):

> I tried to add the toolbar component and I get a syntax error about my
> brackets

First off, [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) is indeed easier and it works like regular HTML, but with the ability to use JavaScript *expressions* (string literals, variables, function calls, etc.), e.g. `<p>Hello, { name }</p>` or `<p>{ Date.now() }</p>`.

Now the thing which caused that syntax error is this part:

```js
className={components-icon-button components-toolbar__control}
```

Because anything inside the brackets (`{ this part }`) is a regular JavaScript expression, so if you're outputting a static string, then it has to be enclosed in single/double quotes:

```js
// Bad
className={components-icon-button components-toolbar__control}

// Good
className={'components-icon-button components-toolbar__control'}
```

But actually, for static attribute values, you could simply do `<attribute>="<value>"`: `className="components-icon-button components-toolbar__control"`, i.e. no need to use the `{ expression }` format. :)

```js
// Static attribute value.
const MyDiv = <div className="foo bar">baz</div>;

// Dynamic attribute value.
const someClass = someFunction() ? 'yes' : 'no';
const MyDiv2 = <div className={ 'foo bar ' + someClass }>baz</div>;

// Same as above, but without using the someClass variable.
const MyDiv3 = <div className={ 'foo bar ' + ( someFunction() ? 'yes' : 'no' ) }>baz</div>;
```

> Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

That's a generic React error which occurs when a (React) component returns two or more adjacent elements instead of one:

- This will result in the above error because unless you return an array of elements (see bullet #3 below), React expects a component to return just a single element:

  ```js
  // This is equivalent to "return 1 2", "const a = (1 2)" or "const a = 1 2" which
  // results in a syntax error :(
  const MyComponent = (
      <div>foo bar</div>
      <p>baz boo</p>
  );
  ```
- But that one single element can contain as many elements as you want. And if that's the case, use a parent element (`div`, `p`, a custom component, etc.) or a (React) [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) — which is exported as `wp.element.Fragment` in the global `window` object on the WordPress editor pages:

  ```js
  // Using Fragment (the short syntax, i.e. <> with </>).
  const MyComponent = (
      <>
          <div>foo bar</div>
          <p>baz boo</p>
      </>
  );

  // Using div as the parent element.
  const MyComponent = (
      <div>
          <div>foo bar</div>
          <p>baz boo</p>
      </div>
  );
  ```
- Or as mentioned above (bullet #1), you can return an array containing the top-level adjacent elements, but a [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) should be set in each element:

  ```js
  // The output/HTML will be the same as the one that uses the Fragment (<> and </>).
  const MyComponent = ([ // <- returns an array
      <div key="one">foo bar</div>,
      <p key="two">baz boo</p>
  ]);
  ```

So in your case, you'd probably want to use:

```js
<>
    <BlockControls>
        ... your code.
    </BlockControls>
    <p>
        ... your code.
    </p>
</>
```

And you can find more insights on the "must be wrapped" error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31284169), but the answers used `React.xxx` which should be [`wp.element.xxx`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-element/) in Gutenberg or the WordPress block editor.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it works: 

`<div>
    <BlockControls>
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton
          className="components-icon-button components-toolbar__control"
          label={__('Update table of contents', 'simpletoc')}
          onClick={function() {
            sendfakeAttribute(props)
          }}
          icon="update"
        />
      </Toolbar>
  </BlockControls>
  <p className={props.className}>
    <ServerSideRender block={props.name} attributes={props.attributes} />
  </p>
  </div>`

Comment: Also note that the original solution used when using WP El works here too, e.g. `[ <p>1</p>,<p>2</p> ]`, if you consider that the tags are transpiled into the original `el(` calls it makes sense why it fails for the same reasons `return 1 2 3;` will generate errors

Comment: Ok. Thank you. The "return 1 2 3" comparisson makes sense.

What about "className="components-icon-button components-toolbar__control"" that seems to work and looks more correct than using: 

className={'components-icon-button components-toolbar__control'}

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell. @Marc, I've updated the answer, but I was just saying `{ <string> }` is wrong and use `{ '<string>' }` instead. :)